# How to filter request based on client in C# (Identity Server 4)

Tags: c#, httprequest, identityserver4, webhooks, clientid

I made this method because the actual project was working with tokens in Header, and for my project I have to read the body (my token is in body). What I did was first checking if the token is under Authorization, if not check the body... But I´ve become the feedback that the best way to solve that is based on my Client, because im the only one reading the token from Body..

```
private string GetTokenFromHeader()
  {
     string value = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
     if (value.IsNull()) //if null, check body. 
        return GoogleGetTokenFromBody(_contextAccessor);
     return value.Substring(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme.Length + 1).Trim();
  }
```

I have no clue how to filter a request by client name, has someone an idea or suggestion?

Comment: Are you logged in? Add a claim which states what client the token was issued to, then during authentication you can validate the client

Comment: yes im logged in, how can I do that? Im sorry but im really new with this :s In my Startup i defined some policies and there i defined some RequireClaim with my ClientDefinition

Comment: You probably have a method in your AccountController, which handles creating the user identity, when that occurs just add a claim to the token which checks the client or ip etc

Comment: you can implement Authorize attributes for your resources to protect, also you can implement your Authorization policy providers and inject into configuration services as singleton object, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-5.0